# "Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect"

Tags: flutter

after reinstalling Flutter 2. I get this error. I cant find what I am missing in? Could you please give me your suggestions?
my error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:666)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect0(HttpURLConnection.java:2739)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2651)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1830)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:268)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:58)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:44)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:61)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
'''
my flutter doctor -v is 
'''
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale ru-RU)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at F:\01-Android_development\flutter
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (9 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at F:\01-Android_development\android-sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = F:\01-Android_development\android-sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\XSkills\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • SM A107F (mobile)                  • R9AM80BHRFJ   • android-arm    • Android 9 (API 28)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 8.1.0 (API 27) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.90
    • Edge (web)                         • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 88.0.705.63

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Wen are you getting this issue?

Comment: Your server isn't running. Start it.

Comment: when i start F5 my app

Answer (score 1):

I encounter into similar situation ,it has something to do with `gradle`. Here is my 5 cents.
Go to the menu of android studio as the following:

`Tools->Flutter->Open Android module in Android Studio`.

It will open the android corresponding project and a window may pop up for proxy configuration if you have.After that , wait and without more accident , it will automatically download `gradle-related` stuff.

Go back to flutter ,problem solved.

This solution will also address this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107008) which however has been closed that I cannot comment.